# Проблема с контекстным меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица истории, когда нажимаю лпм в любом месте страницы показывается меню, как сделать чтобы только в таблице истории работало мое меню, а не на всей странице?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    $('.context-menu').remove();
    if (event.which === 3) {
      var target = $(event.target);
      $('<div/>', {
          class: 'context-menu' // Присваиваем блоку наш css класс контекстного меню:
        })
        .css({
          left: event.pageX + 'px', // Задаем позицию меню на X
          top: event.pageY + 'px' // Задаем позицию меню по Y
        })
        .appendTo('body') // Присоединяем наше меню к body документа:
        .append( // Добавляем пункты меню:
          $('<ul/>').append('<li><a href="#">Удалить</a></li>')
          .append('<li><a href="#">Обновить</a></li>')
        )
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="history">
  <tr class="row">
    <th class="nyr">ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell">${Id}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто - повесь обработчик не на весь документ `$(document).mousedown`, а только на таблицу или ее элемент

Например:

```
$('#history').mousedown
```

или

```
$('.row').mousedown
```

**P.S.**

Для вызова контекстного меню надо использовать обработчик `contextmenu`

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/y396m4h8/

```
$('.block').contextmenu(function(){
  alert('click');
});
```

**P.P.S.**

Небольшое добавление - чтобы не вылезало стандартное выпадающее меню надо сделать так: https://jsfiddle.net/y396m4h8/2/

```
$('.block').on('contextmenu', function(e){
  alert('click');
  e.preventDefault(); // вот эта строка важна!
});
```

Comment: Как отключить стандартное контекстное меню браузера? Они показывается при нажатии на лпм

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y396m4h8/ используй обработчик 'contextmenu'